# How to construct maven build for web application, including building of UI and server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, webpack

Here is the folder structure of our project:

```
src
|
|-frontend
|     |-...
|     |-dist
|
|-java-...
|
|-webapp-...
```

I have following npm scripts:

```
"copy": "copyfiles -f ./src/index.html ./src/favicon.ico ./dist"
"dist": "npm run copy & webpack --env=dist"
```

In Jenkins build, I want maven to build the frontend first, invoking npm *dist* script, then copying content of the dist folder to webapp folder and finally build the java program

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to separate the front-end and the back-end in two different Maven modules in a Maven project, considering these are really two different artifacts. Your modules are ordered like this, for the front-end to be built first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>so-multi-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>so-multi-modules</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>front-end</module>
        <module>back-end</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

The front-end module is mostly a JavaScript application with your favorite JS build tool kickstarted from Maven like so (I use Grunt):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>grunt-deploy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <exec executable="grunt.cmd">
                                <arg value="deploy" />
                                <arg value="--force" />
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Your back-end would then use the antrun plugin to copy the front-end where you need it to be.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-front-end</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="../front-end/target/path/to/dist" tofile="${project.build.directory}/path/to/dist/dest" overwrite="true" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```